# Setting up a dynamic spreadsheet to join with feature layer in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, excel, google-sheets

I am building a map of about 500 storage units that are being acquired and relocated, each unit is represented as a polygon. Each polygon is coded by Unit Number and will go through about 5 different category changes (vacant, notice to proceed, etc.), all of this is being tracked in a Google Sheet. Is there a way to dynamically join this spreadsheet to the feature layer in ArcMap by Unit Number and have the map automatically (or semi-automatically) update the symbology as the spreadsheet changes?

This question was asked in 2016 and the response was to use an access database, I don't think that advice is really relevant anymore. I've seen tutorials of linking Google Sheets to ArcGIS Online, but that appears to require coordinate data and is only for placing points as far as I understand.

I am currently using ArcMap 10.8.2. I could switch to ArcGIS Pro if that's the only way to make this happen. I don't currently have access to ArcGIS Online, but could potentially get access if the solution involves it.I could also pivot away from Google Sheets to Excel.

Comment: Please include a link to the earlier Q&A that you mention.

Comment: ArcGIS Online with Map Author privileges would be a layer you can edit in ArcGIS Pro and it would update the layer in real-time, multiple viewers can view the layer at the same time and would update with your category changes. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/edit-features-mv.htm (note there maybe costs for additional licenses. contact esri for more information)